# PEMDAS Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, windows

**EDIT 2:**
*fixed some grammar and made it easier to understand.

I need help on building a PEMDAS application in vb.net. I want it to solve an inputted equation like this for example: 4 – 3(4 –2(6 – 3)) ÷ 2. I am trying to make it so that when input something into a text box and then click a button it will display the answer of that equation on a label. I first tried coding the section for looking for the parentheses, but it didn't work. I'm trying to make the program look for parentheses inside the equation and then depending on what the operator is inside of the parentheses, it will add, subtract, divide, or multiply the two numbers inside. My code is :

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Property ValidChars As String

    Private Property Num2 As Object

    Private Property Num1 As Object

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ValidChars = ("()")
        If TextBox1.Text = ValidChars Then
            TextBox1.Text() = Num1 + Num2
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Any help will be well appreciated.

Thanks, bye!

**EDIT 1:**

Hello I need help on building a PEMDAS application and I need help with it. I have a textbox and a button that I need to press on to get the answer and the answer is going to be on a label. I first did the parentheses which is the part that I didn't get working. What I need is a thing that could find the numbers in the parentheses and then if it shows a + , / , - , * , then it will do the thing but I need help with that. My code is : An Order of Operations program like this for example this : 4 – 3(4 –2(6 – 3)) ÷ 2 and the answer for it  .

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Property ValidChars As String

    Private Property Num2 As Object

    Private Property Num1 As Object

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ValidChars = ("()")
        If TextBox1.Text = ValidChars Then
            TextBox1.Text() = Num1 + Num2
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Any help will be well appreciated.

Thanks Bye!

Comment: Please show your code.  What isn't working exactly?  Are you getting an error?

Comment: You should add your code by editing your post, not adding the code as a comment. Cheers.

Comment: By the way I'm kind of new to programming.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more about what you want? The code doesn't seem to make any sense.

Comment: I know it is because I need help with it and I'm new to programming .

Comment: Well I actually mean you should be posting something that will give us an idea of what you want. Like give a scenario and give the result you want. Nobody can help you if all the information you have is this. Give us a little something and we'll give you what you want.

Comment: An Order of Operations program.

Comment: If you want us to help, you need to clearly explain the problem you're trying to solve. I have no clue what "I need is a thing that could find the numbers in the parentheses and then if it shows a + , / , - , * , then it will do the thing" means. "I need a thing that does a thing that might do another thing that might do something different. Can you help me?" You need to [edit] your question and add a more clear explanation of the problem. If you can't exert the effort to ask the question clearly, it's a little unfair to expect us to exert effort to try and answer it.

Comment: A problem like this for example this : 4 – 3(4 –2(6 – 3)) ÷ 2
and the answer for it .

Comment: You may need to read up a bit more before you start on this venture.  Take a look at how to use [Regular Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312(v=vs.110).aspx), [Parsing strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397679.aspx) into [numbers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384043.aspx), casting, and acessing your form controls.

Comment: @KenWhite, your last statement nailed it.

Comment: now can you answer my question?

Comment: @TheVB10Guy: You seem to be having trouble with clicking the link to [edit] your question to provide the details, despite the number of times people have given you the [edit] link to [edit] your question. Can you [edit] your question instead of posting information in comments? The information is much easier to find if you [edit] your question, and in the [edit] you provide the details there. Can you [edit] your question? Thanks for the [edit] in advance. [If that link is hard to click you could try clicking this one](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21198953/edit) instead. Thanks again.

Comment: I don't have a problem for clicking the link.

Comment: Don't get us wrong @TheVB10Guy. We're all trying to help here. So don't feel bad and start learning. We all gotta start somewhere.

Comment: Ok Thanks @chris_techno25: But can you try to help me and not vote bad because I'm new to programming and StackOverflow.

Comment: @TheVB10Guy, I never voted you down. It wasn't me. Check my solution below if it helps.

Comment: I mean that I want to be able to type a question and get the answer not the answer in the code that every time will show the same answer

Comment: @KenWhite I tried answering a c question on stackoverflow today, but then it said "We are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.", since you were one of the people who closed this, can you tell me how to gain back reputation so I can post my answer. I don't know what I can do to resolve this, and yes I have looked at the help center, but it didn't help. Also, I'm sorry for not understanding your comments, I didn't know English very well back then, I hope you understand.

Comment: Search on the exact first sentence of that message at [meta]. There's an entire page of information on how to get your account reinstated.

Comment: @KenWhite Ok thanks!

Comment: @KenWhite I tried to make it more clear, check it now.

Comment: @KenWhite can you please check it out?

Comment: Can you stop blowing up my inbox? My full-time job is not babysitting your post. I'll get to it when I can. Stop nagging - it's not in your best interest to irritate the people you're asking to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you're looking for. This built-in function has its limits especially if the expression involves trigonometric functions but this should be enough for your needs.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        Dim answer = New DataTable().Compute(TextBox1.Text, Nothing)
        MsgBox(answer)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Syntax Error")
    End Try
End Sub
```

If you want a more challenging approach, which I recommend you would, you can create your own algorithm to manipulate strings and get numbers within to solve the expression. String manipulation functions should be what you'll ever need such as Mid, Split, Contains, etc.

Comment: This is close but it only shows the answer to a problem that is inside the code but I want it to be like a calculator.

Comment: Hmmm, what do you mean like a calculator? Can you explain?

Comment: That I type in the equation in the textbox and when I press on the button , the msgbox will show the answer

Comment: `MSScriptControl.dll` does that already.

Comment: can you please vote for more because if not then I won't be able to ask questions.

Comment: I edited the answer. Type in the expression into the Textbox you have and click on the button. It should msgbox the answer.